# Wordpress UPDATE queries on MySQL database stuck

Tags: mysql, apache-2.4, wordpress, mariadb, optimization

I have an **Amazon 24XL server**

- 96 Cores
- 378 GB RAM
- Database size 5.7G
- Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
- PHP 7.3.16
- mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.22-MariaDB

I have only one WordPress site where users read articles, there are 4-5 small plugins 
One plugins is used to add the points and rewards in my subscribers profile.
When there are around 2500 Users on my site there are around 3000+ UPDATE queries that runs to update the table
'wp_custom_points_user'

The issue is that the queries stuck in updating I can't find the way to fix those things
However server has much RAM , CPU available but due to queries on the same table it stuck and caused 502 on my site.
I am looking to optimize MySQL to cater concurrent update queries as they are taking longer to respond and I suspect there are some locks. However I have all tables with indexing and using InnoDB

[image]

Here is the SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

```
=====================================
2020-04-06 13:45:46 0x7f934bf24700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 27 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 8196 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 0 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 8196
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 15589494
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 41500023
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 154525943, OS waits 1459106
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 10328037, OS waits 40587
RW-sx spins 71982, rounds 547220, OS waits 3916
Spin rounds per wait: 154525943.00 RW-shared, 10328037.00 RW-excl, 7.60 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 351880322
Purge done for trx's n:o < 351880319 undo n:o < 0 state: running
History list length 1
... truncated...
mpact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000000000; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 80000000000000; asc        ;;
 3: len 4; hex 80004cd6; asc   L ;;
 4: len 4; hex 800186b0; asc     ;;

------------------
---TRANSACTION 351861705, ACTIVE 40 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 421774, OS thread handle 140270896170752, query id 8187691 localhost wpdatabayf Updating
UPDATE `wp_custom_points_user` SET `total_points` = '18900' WHERE `user_id` = 188768
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 40 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1468 page no 5 n bits 568 index PRIMARY of table `wpdatabayf`.`wp_custom_points_user` trx id 351861705 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000000000; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 80000000000000; asc        ;;
 3: len 4; hex 80004cd6; asc   L ;;
 4: len 4; hex 800186b0; asc     ;;

---BUFFER POOL 1
.
.
.
.
---BUFFER POOL 31
Buffer pool size   8192
Free buffers       1725
Database pages     6096
Old database pages 2253
Modified db pages  183
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 2.340
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 5594, created 502, written 12349
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.74 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 6096, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
2 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=72108, Main thread ID=140323093444352, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 88380, updated 193228, deleted 34011, read 84305568368
11.44 inserts/s, 21.74 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 12469107.55 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

## UPDATE

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_custom_points_user;
+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                            | Create Table                                         |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| wp_custom_points_user | CREATE TABLE `wp_custom_points_user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `total_points` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ixd_uc_tzs_wp_custom_points_user` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=199180 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+

SHOW INDEX FROM wp_custom_points_user;
+----------------------------------+------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                            | Non_unique | Key_name                                    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------------------------+------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| wp_custom_points_user            |          0 | PRIMARY                                     |            1 | id          | A         |      171334 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_custom_points_user            |          0 | ixd_uc_tzs_wp_custom_points_user            |            1 | user_id     | A         |      171334 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------------------------------+------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Can you share table and index descriptions?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_custom_points_user`.  Is there something else (like a big ALTER) running?  Meanwhile, that server is 100 times as powerful as you need for the task.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Thank you for response , I have updated the question with requested details can you check now?

Comment: @RickJames Thank you for response, Could you please check the updated question?

Comment: When do you commit the update?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit is set to 2 is that what you mean to ask?

Comment: No.  By default, autocommit is on, so the update is commited immediately.  You could have switched autocommit off (is this possible via .ini?) and programmed the commit.

Comment: Its the default value where commits are done automatically @GerardH.Pille

Comment: When a subscriber visits your site, how often is his record updated?

Comment: When a subscriber read a post the point will be added to the table , one query  per post per customer @GerardH.Pille

Comment: And your site is protected against visits by bots?  Because they can read really fast!

Comment: @GerardH.Pille yes I have blocked all Bots at Nginx

if ($http_user_agent ~* (kinsta-bot|X-Middleton|IndeedBot|......ALOT MORE......|brands-bot) ) {
return 403;
}

Comment: So a bot telling you he's Google Chrome can run rampage?

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.